# PID Line follower with tank treads

Tags: c

I have made a (pretty bad) line follower.

Here is a sketch to roughly know the shape of the robot and location of the treads and sensors

```
[-] 0  0 [-] // 0 = color sensor
[-]------[-] // - = robot body
[-]------[-] // [-] = tank tread
[-]      [-]
```

Here's what it does:

- get Red, Green & Blue, make average of sensor 1 readings, do the same for 2
- subtract to get value
- this value will go through the PID part
- steer with calculated steering
- repeat (all of this is in a loop)

I use RGB and not reflected intensity (which is what is commonly used), because sometimes I need to detect if there's green color under the sensor (if there is, turn).

The real problem comes with the steering part. Unfortunately, it only accelerates a motor, meaning that in very tight turns we just lose the line.

Optimally, it should compensate a bit with the other motor (maybe going in the other direction?), but I am not sure how to calculate the speed of the motor, nor how to enforce this very strict line following policy.

Here is the code (I am also very grateful for any kind of tips on how to clean up the code! This is my first project in C :D ). I am not asking to read it all (it is pretty long), you could also just look at the steering function, and work your way back to `rawFollowLine`, this should hopefully shorten the code.

```
void rawFollowLine(int speed, float Kp, float Ki, float Kd){

    _checkInit();

    set_sensor_mode(sn_lx_color, "RGB-RAW");
    set_sensor_mode(sn_rx_color, "RGB-RAW");
    //printAllSensors();

    int wasBlackCounter = 0;
    int wasBlack = 0;
    int lastBlack = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {

        if (isTerminating == 1)
        {
            killMotors(0);
            break;
        }

        int greenCheck = rawGreenCheck(&wasBlack, &wasBlackCounter, &lastBlack);


        if (wasBlack == 1){
            wasBlackCounter++;
            if (wasBlackCounter > 50){
                wasBlackCounter = 0;
                wasBlack = 0;
            }
        }
        if (greenCheck == 1)
        {
            // lx is green
            killMotors(1);
            usleep(400 * 1000);
            drive(200, 70);
            waitIfMotorIsRunning();
            killMotors(1);
            pivotTurn(-90);
        } 
        else if (greenCheck == 2)
        {
            // rx is green
            killMotors(1);
            usleep(400 * 1000);
            drive(200, 70);
            waitIfMotorIsRunning();
            killMotors(1);
            pivotTurn(90);
        }
        else if (greenCheck == 3)
        {
            // both rx and lx are green
            killMotors(1);
            turn(180);
        }
        else if (greenCheck == 5) 
        {
            if(lastBlack == 2)
            {
                lastBlack = 0;
                drive(100, -200);
                //pivotTurn(50);
            }
            else if (lastBlack == 1)
            {
                lastBlack = 0;
                drive(100, -200);
                //pivotTurn(-50);
            } else {
                pidLineRaw(speed, Kp, Ki, Kd, &lastBlack);  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pidLineRaw(speed, Kp, Ki, Kd, &lastBlack);  
        }

    }
    killMotors(1);

}


int rawGreenCheck(int *wasBlack, int *wasBlackCounter, int *lastBlack)
{
    // Some documentation
    // return nums:
    // 3 = double green
    // 2 = right green
    // 1 = left green
    // 0 = no green 
    int lx_red;
    int lx_green;
    int lx_blue;

    int rx_red;
    int rx_green;
    int rx_blue;

    get_sensor_value(0, sn_lx_color, &lx_red);
    get_sensor_value(0, sn_rx_color, &rx_red);

    get_sensor_value(1, sn_lx_color, &lx_green);
    get_sensor_value(1, sn_rx_color, &rx_green);

    get_sensor_value(2, sn_lx_color, &lx_blue);
    get_sensor_value(2, sn_rx_color, &rx_blue);

    //printf("rx_red %d\n", rx_red);
    rx_red = (rx_red * rx_ratio_r);
    rx_green = (rx_green * rx_ratio_g);
    rx_blue = (rx_blue * rx_ratio_b);
    //printf("rx_red (again) %d\n", rx_red);

    if(
        lx_red < 55 && 
        lx_green > 90 && 
        lx_blue < 55 && 

        rx_red < 55 && 
        rx_green > 90 && 
        rx_blue < 55
        )
    {
        // rx and lx see green
        if (*wasBlack == 1)
        {
            // Apparently we crossed an intersection!
            printf("Apparently we crossed an intersection!\n");
            // We need to go straight.
            *wasBlack = 0;
            *wasBlackCounter = 0;
            return 0;
        } 
        else
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    else if(lx_red < 55 && lx_green > 90 && lx_blue < 55)
    {
        // lx sees green
        return 1;
    }
    else if(rx_red < 55 && rx_green > 90 && rx_blue < 55)
    {
        // rx sees green
        return 2;
    }
    else if(rx_red < 50 && rx_green < 50 && rx_blue < 50 && lx_red < 50 && lx_green < 50 && lx_blue < 50)
    {
        // rx and lx see black
        // this is needed if the intersection has the green tiles after the black line
        printf("We are on the line? Is this an intersection?\n");
        *wasBlack = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(lx_red < 55 && lx_green < 55 && lx_blue < 55)
    {
        // lx = right sees black
        // this is needed if the intersection has the green tiles after the black line
        //printf("We are on the line? Is this an intersection?\n");
        killMotor(1, motor[R]);
        rotateTillBlack(motor[L], sn_rx_color);
        //printf("ASS2\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(rx_red < 55 && rx_green < 55 && rx_blue < 55)
    {
        // rx = left sees black
        killMotor(1, motor[L]);
        rotateTillBlack(motor[R], sn_lx_color);
        //printf("ASS1\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //*lx_color_status = 0;
    //*rx_color_status = 0;
    *lastBlack = 0;
    return 0;
}

void pidLineRaw(int speed, float Kp, float Ki, float Kd, int *lastBlack)
{

    int red_lx_color;
    int red_rx_color;

    int green_lx_color;
    int green_rx_color;

    int blue_lx_color;
    int blue_rx_color;

    int lx_color;
    int rx_color;

    int last_error = 0;

    int integral = 0;
    int derivative = 0;

    //float Kp = 0.1;
    //float Ki = 0;
    //float Kd = 0;

    //set_sensor_mode(sn_lx_color, "COL-REFLECT");
    //set_sensor_mode(sn_rx_color, "COL-REFLECT");

    get_sensor_value(0, sn_lx_color, &red_lx_color);
    get_sensor_value(0, sn_rx_color, &red_rx_color);

    get_sensor_value(1, sn_lx_color, &green_lx_color);
    get_sensor_value(1, sn_rx_color, &green_rx_color);

    get_sensor_value(2, sn_lx_color, &blue_lx_color);
    get_sensor_value(2, sn_rx_color, &blue_rx_color);

    lx_color = (red_lx_color + green_lx_color+ blue_lx_color)/3;
    rx_color = ( (red_rx_color*rx_ratio_r) + (green_rx_color*rx_ratio_g) + (blue_rx_color*rx_ratio_b))/3;

    if(*lastBlack == 0)
    {
        int error = lx_color - rx_color;
        integral = integral + error;
        derivative = error - last_error;
        last_error = error;

        int steering_val = (error * Kp) + (integral * Ki) + (derivative * Kd);
        // printf("error: %d\nsteering: %d\n",error, steering_val);
        move_steering(-steering_val, speed, 1, 0);
    } else if (*lastBlack == 1)
    {
        printf("lx_color_status\n");
        move_steering(35, speed, 1, 0);
        move_steering(-2, speed, 1, 0);
    } 
    else if (*lastBlack == 2)
    {
        printf("rx_color_status\n");
        move_steering(-35, speed, 1, 0);
        move_steering(2, speed, 1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("HMMM: %d\n", *lastBlack);
        exit(666);
    }
}
static void _getSteeringSpeed(int speed, int *lx_speed, int *rx_speed, int steering)
{
    if(steering > 100 || steering < -100)
    {
        printf("Yo wtf steering is %d\n", steering);
    } 
    else 
    {
        int speed_factor = (50 - abs(steering)) / 50;
        *lx_speed = speed;
        *rx_speed = speed;

        if(steering >= 0)
        {
            *rx_speed = *rx_speed * speed_factor;
        } 
        else 
        {
            *lx_speed = *lx_speed * speed_factor;
        }
    }
}
```

Some parts are omitted, yes, they are not required to solve the problem.

I am also extremely sorry as there might be unused variables and such. I am working on refactoring the project, I'll update the post when I'm done.

So, summing everything up, I need to make sure that the steering part properly turns and follows the line. How do I do that? Is the code that I wrote even suitable? I'm guessing the steering itself might need some sort of feedback loop, to check if it's on the line?

Comment: Could you precise your question?

Comment: I do not see a ***question***.

Comment: @AlainMerigot The steering part is the problem. I've tried to give more context for a better answer.

Comment: That is a lot of code to ask someone to read through.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It is, yes. But then again, if I omit more code people are going to complain about not having enough context. And though you could read it all to give a precise answer, you could also just look at the steering and see where (and what?) it's lacking, to follow the line properly.

Comment: But we have no way to test anything. If I understand correctly, the code is more or less working, but you are not happy with the control algorithm. Control theory is a full scientific domain and most people here (including me) will not be able to tell you if you should increase feedback or not.

Comment: @AlainMerigot I know. It's not about increasing feedback though. I am not asking about tuning the PID. The algorithm I am using (the `_getSteeringSpeed`, mostly) is fundamentally broken. It works, of course, but performance is poor. Even pseudocode works for me. I am just burnt out and I really need to fix this.

Comment: @A.Dandelion This question doesn't belong here. You will get better help on the "Code Review" forum.

Comment: Why are there `killMotor` commands everywhere? Shouldn't you let the PID do that?